# VPN Gateway - Split incoming and outgoing across two internet connections

Tags: networking, vpn, internet

I have been struggling to find information for this specific configuration for a week or so now.. please forgive me as i am a developer and my networking knowledge is limited.. to say the least...

So i have a vpn server with multiple internet connections connected to it however in this case we will just use two connections. I want to be able to connect to the server on broadband connection#1. Whilst connected i want all my web traffic to go through a broadband connection#2 to the internet...

[my computer] ----- connection#1----- [vpnserver] ---- connection#2----[internet]

The server has 5 connections in total but i only need to use one for incoming and one for outgoing traffic... if that makes sense... 
PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE can somebody point me in any direction at all, even if you could share some information on what this method would be called! Any help appreciated!! <3 <3 <3

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the VPN, the server needs to listen on a specific IP (or all of them), using a directive such as (for OpenVPN) :

```
# Which local IP address should OpenVPN
# listen on? (optional)
;local a.b.c.d
```

For the outgoing data, if you wish to route all data on the server to a specific interface, you can play with the metric of the interfaces. Packets will go out to the interface with the lowest metric (all else being equal). If you want only VPN data to go out this way, you can use Policy Based Routing (PBR) to (for example) route all packets from the VPN subnet to a specific connection.

Comment: You my friend are a HERO! Thats the information i needed to get me going! I'll Update here when i get it restored and post my solution. 
Thanks floxOne!